# Loop cut not going across quad

Tags: modeling

My loop cut stops here, despite all my faces being quads. How do I get it to go all the way around?[image]

I merged doubled vertices and recalculated normals but it didn't help.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: also check ifyou have an inner face

Comment: I bet it's not a quad .. that it just looks like one.. jiggle all those verts around.. H hide the face, and see if there's one underneath...